# Cloning of a div in html using javascript with new id

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic

I am getting response as json from server e.g.

```
{
"data": [
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Tree",
    "category": "Green"
},
{
    "id":"456",
    "name":"Paper",
    "category":"Green"
},
{
    "id":"789",
    "name":"Polybag",
    "category":"Red"
}
],
"string": "Hello World"
}
```

And in my HTML i have a div like this..

```
<div class="pageHeader">
            <div id="pageInfo">
                <div id="pageNameBox">
                    <p><span class="title">Name:</span><label id="pageName">Tree</label></p>
                </div>
                <div id="pageCatBox">
                    <p><span class="title">Category:</span><label id="pageCat">Green</label></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="expandCollapseButton">
                <input type="button" name="excoll" value="Expand" class="fbButton">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now depending upon the number of items i recieve from the server,in this case 3, i want to clone this div and use the values received from server to generate a new div with the id we got from server. I don't want to use jQuery, i know i can clone a component but i am not sure how will i give values to the new components and how will i set the id of the component.

Answer (score 3):

That would be [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode), and it's pretty straight forward, something like

```
var elem = document.getElementById('pageHeader'); // get an element

var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);// clone it,"true" is a deep clone with children

clone.id = 'the_new_id'; // give it a new ID

parent.appendChild(clone); // put it somewhere
```

Note that you should change the ID of all children as well, otherwise you'll have duplicates